# How to send email when input query Salesforce object component(postgresql) fetching or output table (mssql) unloading zero record or empty records

Tags: salesforce, ab-initio

In an existing graph I wanted to have a check on any one of the query Salesforce object component or output table component weather it is writting or unloading zero records and i wanted get notified by email about the same. What will be the better way out of these : creating wrapper script, using parameters, adding the transformations, creating intermediate files, use run program, end script or writing stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in Graph. component for send Email with attachment is available in GDE. just do not forget to change layer number to highest one for Email component.